# some URL query variable not working in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform, concrete5

My URL: `http://www.capstonehomes-mn.com/index.php?cID=127&ccm_token=1363683205:04db0d40a58c3559286c525f299e1fce".`

This site was developed using `concrete5`. This url passing 2 query variables & calling to this page using jquery ajax form. This url doesnt display query variables & its value. what can be problem?.

I would like to get all query variable values in this screenshot: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/14061/20130319-prv0-77kb.jpg`at the time of printing`$_REQUEST`.

Some URLs working correctly.

My PHP code in target page:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] working correctly.

If I will paste this URL in browser address bar query variables working correctly. but not in ajax call.I'm seeing page not found in ajax call ( http://my.jetscreenshot.com/14061/20130319-iami-27kb.jpg )

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're looking for. Can you provide more information?

Comment: I would like to get query variable & its values. for e.g In the above URL at the time of writing print_r($_REQUEST); in php code answer should be like array (cID=>127 ,ccm_token=>136368....)

Comment: If I will paste this URL query variables working correctly. but not in ajax call.I'm seeing page not found in ajax call

Comment: You should make sure you are properly URL encoding your name-value pairs, you shouldn't be able to have an unencoded `:` at that point in your URL. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: This URL "http://www.capstonehomes-mn.com/index.php?cID=423&ccm_token=1363687163:cc8e4e7be867e17c63c6f331ea4e67ea" working correctly without error at the time of ajax form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Some frameworks using an own API for the request part. And in some cases they unset the global $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST variables.

If you look at the [concrete5 documentation](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/system/request/) you can see that this framework uses such a API. I think if you use `$req = Request::get();` then you can print the request variables.

Comment: some URLs working correctly. 3-5 URLs not working like above.

Comment: Please provider more URLs and describe which one works and which one doesn't work. Maybe it's a routing problem.

Comment: In Google Chrome it works correctly.Already fixed some url issues using chrome. but i need to fix in firefox browser